# Stop event propagation in NativeScript ios tap event

Tags: nativescript, stoppropagation

I have a `tap` event in my code. Its parent(not an immediate parent) also has `tap` event. In Android, everything works fine. But in `ios`, the event is propagating upwards to that parent. How to stop that event propagation (such as `event.stopPropagation()` in `javascript`).

Sample XML code:

```
<StackLayout  tap="newsDetails" data-args="{{ $value }}">
     <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" >
         <Label text="Share" class="icon" tap="shareNews" data-args="{{ $value }}"/>
     </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**Note: I am using  NativeScript core**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boolean property [isUserInteractionEnabled](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_layouts_grid_layout_.gridlayout.html#isuserinteractionenabled), however, this won't solve the issue as it will stop the user interaction for all nested elements as well. It is simply not good practice to have multiple tap events in the same area.

Comment: Is there any other solution to do this as it does not meet my requirement.

Comment: Nope - this is just the way event propagation works on iOS. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067865/propagating-touch-events-through-sibling-subviews

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on android, here's a simple solution i came up with, not elegant but works :

```
private ignoreTap = false;

shareNews(){
  this.ignoreTap = true;
  // ...
}

newsDetails(){
  if (this.ignoreTap) { this.ignoreTap = false; return; }
  // ...
}
```

The flag ignoreTap will stop the root function execution.